# How to change the message 'Allow "App" to access your location ' in ios

Tags: ios, gps

I know this is default message shown by IOS as a privacy policy to display this message if your app is using the gps location.

My question is I want to change this message with my own message . If anybody knows that please let me know so I may change it.

For better understanding screenshot given below:

[image: Image with the message]

Thanks
Surjan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is in your app's plist. Add in a row for NSLocationUsageDescription (or if you're using the formatted values, its the Privacy Usage - Location). Whatever your description is should appear in the alert view from then on.

Comment: Thanks Serenn for quick response , I will try that